# Different wifi networks returning different websites for same URL

Tags: networking, mac, wireless-networking, dns, cname

I've recently changed the CNAME for my website but it's stuck on the old page. I've tried flushing my DNS cache, clearing my browser cache and restarting my Mac. I've even checked my HOSTS file, no references to this site.

Nothing works, but the page loads fine on other devices. Strangely enough, the page even loads if I change to a different wi-fi network on this Mac.

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the device responsible for proxing DNS - typically this would be the router.  My guess is that the old details are cached in the routers DNS proxy.